# cakeDC Search and checkboxes

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakedc

I have a search form with a checkbox.

**index.ctp**

```
...
echo $this->Form->input('active', 
[
    'label' => 'Select only active users',
]);
...
```

I'd like the following behavior:

- if `active` is unchecked list all records (no condition added to the query)
- if `active` is checked list only records where `active = true`

Instead, because of the hidden field, when active is unchecked a value of 0 is passed to the component and only the records with `active = false` are showed

if I remove the hidden field:

```
echo $this->Form->input('active', 
[
    'label' => 'Select only active users',
    'hiddenField' => false
]);
```

then `active=1` is passed in the GET parameters and it's not possible to uncheck the input anymore.

I solved creating my own hidden field instead of the one created by cakephp and setting its value to null

```
$this->Form->hidden('active', ['value' => ''])
```

but I don't like this solution. Is there any way to tell cake so set the default value of the hidden field to null or to change the cakeDC Search plugin default behavior when working with checkboxes?

Comment: Amm, can't you alter the condition based on that field's value? I mean, something like: `if(!isset($active) || $active == 0) { unset($active); //or change the condition in the query}`

Comment: Yes, I can do something like that. But I want to find a more clean solution so I don't have to remember to put that code everytime I have one checkbox in my form.

Comment: Thats why I invented the emptyValue param etc. This way using 0 for it it will just ignore that filter as you want it to work.

Comment: thanks @mark. But I ask you if you please can detail how should I use emptyValue. Be patient but I read all the documentation and I did not realized it was related to my issue...

Comment: You simply tell the behavior that 0 is the zeroValue. That has the same effect as your solution. Both work, but mine is configuration on the behavior level and yours on the view form helper level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following mark's comment here is the solution

template file

```
...
echo $this->Form->input('active', 
[
    'label' => 'Select only active users',
]);
...
```

table file

```
$filterArgs = [
    'active' => [
        'name' => 'active',
        'type' => 'value',
    ],
]
```

controller file

```
$presetVars = array(
    'active' => [
        'name' => 'afa',
        'type' => 'value',
        'emptyValue' => '0',
    ],
);
```

(honestly I still don't understand why we have to set the parameter both in the table file and in the controller)